# Jquery toggle('slide') only slides once

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-hover

I am very new to jquery so please forgive me in advance if my question is too basic. I am having some problems with a hover slide effect that seems to be a mixture of CSS and jquery issue. 
When i hover over the image it slides over to the end of the image perfectly well the first time, but then it seems that the hover effect only slides half way from under the first element the second time, instead of starting from the image sliding over the the end.

I have tried many other possibilities for this but so far have had no luck, i would be very grateful if someone can point me in the right direction :)

An example of what i am trying to achieve can be found here

http://jsfiddle.net/robolist/rK4GD/

```
$('.proimg').hover(function(event) {
      $('.boxcaption',this).stop().toggle( 'slide' );
}).on('mouseleave',function(event) {
      $('.boxcaption',this).stop().toggle( 'slide' )});
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: no question is 'too basic'!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use toggle on hover, you don't need to do the the mouseleave event. Also note that stop takes to boolean parameters, first for clear queue, second for jump to end:

Just do:

```
$('.proimg').hover(function(event) {
    $('.boxcaption',this).stop(true, true).toggle( 'slide' );
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rK4GD/10/

See: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: Hi @Bernhard Poiss, Many thanks for your help, I had originally tried something similar to that but then the hover effect is inconsistent and becomes 'jerky' and sometimes swaps from cover on hover to uncover on hover

Comment: @LearningJquery: Your main issue why you get inconsitencies is event bubbling which causes the hover event to be triggered a second time when the element is being slid into view. To sort that out the actual element used to slide in `.boxcaption` should not be nested within the element triggering the slide `.proimg` You could also hack it and add a `stopPropagation()` call to the `.boxcaption` element's `mouseenter`. Similar to this: [**http://jsfiddle.net/RsmxQ/**](http://jsfiddle.net/RsmxQ/)

Comment: @LearningJquery: Glad you got something to work. On Stackoverflow we don't set issues to solved in the title of the question but instead you mark the answer as accepted that helped you solve your issue. That indicates to future users what has worked for you.